# '[Object object]' is displayed instead of label in Vue.js datalist

Tags: vue.js, html-datalist

I'm using `<datalist>` drop-down menu to display group names in our project.

```
<data-list
    ref="groupName"
    name="groupName"
    label="Groups: "
    :options="groupList"
></data-list>
.....
methods:{
    groupList(){
        return this.$store.getters['Groups/getGroups']
    }
}
```

But this is displayed in my UI:

[image: screenshot]

I actually want the dropdown to display the `label` field, which is a group name, and I'll get the value of it. The structure of returned value looks like this:

```
[
 {label: "test", value: 14},
 {label: "Test1", value: 16},
 {label: "Test2", value: 17},
 {label: "Test3", value: 18},
]
```

Comment: Just append the label property.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal How or what do you mean?

Comment: `this.$store.getters['Groups/getGroups'].label`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Opppsss. seems no data is displayed with that one..

Comment: Anyone has an idea with this one?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the bug is in your `data-list` component. Most likely you have something like this:

```
<!-- XXX: DON'T DO THIS -->
<option v-for="option in options" :value="option">{{option}}</option>
```

```js
Vue.component('data-list', {
  props: ['label', 'options'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <label for="myinput">{{label}}</label>
      <input id="myinput" list="mydata">
      <datalist id="mydata">
        <!-- XXX: DON'T DO THIS -->
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option">
          {{option}}
        </option>
      </datalist>
    </div>`,
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      groupList: [
        {label: "test", value: 14},
        {label: "Test1", value: 16},
        {label: "Test2", value: 17},
        {label: "Test3", value: 18},
      ]
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <data-list label="Groups: " :options="groupList"></data-list>
</div>
```

But you actually need to set the value of `<option>` to `option.value` and its inner text to `{{option.label}}` (matching your item's data structure):

```
<option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">{{option.label}}</option>
```

```js
Vue.component('data-list', {
  props: ['label', 'options'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <label for="myinput">{{label}}</label>
      <input id="myinput" list="mydata">
      <datalist id="mydata">
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">
          {{option.label}}
        </option>
      </datalist>
    </div>`,
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      groupList: [
        {label: "test", value: 14},
        {label: "Test1", value: 16},
        {label: "Test2", value: 17},
        {label: "Test3", value: 18},
      ]
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <data-list label="Groups: " :options="groupList"></data-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we get it's `value` with the selected label?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the root problem might be in your data-list component. Can you show the code for that component?

Answer (score 0):

you can to use like this in html and js.

actually following code is not a component.

sample HTML code

```
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option v-for="lst in groupList" v-bind:value="lst">{{lst.label}}</option>  
</datalist>
```

---

sample Vue.js code

```
data:{
  groupObj: {},
  groupList: []
},
methods:{
    groupList(){
        this.groupList = this.$store.getters['Groups/getGroups'];
    },    
},
mounted(){
 this.groupList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question as "How to work with objects in datalists in vue.js"

### what are datalists?

- datalists provides just templates to fill other controls.
- mostly used with text input to provide combobox functionallity (allow also new content to be selected)
- At this time implementation in browsers vary greatly, so better to just rely on basic label rendering (don't use value, since browsers handle it differently)

### using it in vue with objects

Idea is to use strings and check on every input change if we have a perfect match. Using `:value` will show the id in chrome, which is probably not what you want. This doesn't work with same-named labels, but then again, such an input makes little sense in that case.

```js
Vue.component('test-data-list', {
  props: ['label', 'options', 'value'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <label for="myinput">{{label}}</label>
      <input id="myinput" list="data" @change="change" :value="getValue">
      <datalist id="data">
        <option v-for="option in options">
          {{option.label}}
        </option>
      </datalist>
    </div>`,
  computed: {
    getValue() {
      return this.value ? this.value.label : '';
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change(e) {
      let value = e.currentTarget.value;
      if (value) {
        let sel = this.options.filter(c => c.label == value);
        if (sel.length == 1) {
          this.selection = sel[0];
        } else {
          this.selection = {
            label: value,
            isNew: true
          }
        }
      } else {
        this.selection = undefined;
      }
      this.$emit('input', this.selection)
    }
  }

});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      result: undefined,
      groupList: [{
          label: "something",
          id: 1
        },
        {
          label: "this too",
          id: 2
        },
        {
          label: "something different",
          id: 3
        }
      ]
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    Selected:
    <span v-if="result">
      "{{ result.label }}" 
      <span v-if="result.isNew">New!</span>
    <span v-else> old object with id:{{result.id}}</span>
    </span>
    <span v-else>nothing</span>
  </div>
  <test-data-list label="Select" :options="groupList" v-model="result"></test-data-list>
</div>
```